Azure SQL Server - Is ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly always honored?
I am using Azure SQL database instance (Business Critical, Read Scale-out enabled) and I would like to offload some of the traffic to Read-Only replicas.

Does adding ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly to connection string always force traffic to read replicas, or connections might end up on primary database as well?
Does SSRS Server 2019 support this parameter?

Thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

modern versions of SSRS do allow ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly.

Answer to (1) -
ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly is a client request, when attempting to connect it asks for target that accepts ReadOnly (RO) workload.
the server is looking for suitable target

Always On secondary replica
Geo-Replication secondary replica
Read Scale-out

if non of them found, it will go by default to the primary ReadWrite (RW) replica.
From server side, you may control if read only connection will be accepted by the primary replica or not.
Summary, from client side this is only a statement about the type of workload, is possible the connection will be routed to RO target.
if RO target is not available the connection will go to the primary RW target.
if the target is RW and configured to reject RO workload the connection will fail.
Answer to (2) -
As this is a connection string property it does not really matter to the client app as long as you provide your connection property as connection string.
more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/sql-server-native-client-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery?view=sql-server-ver15#read-only-routing
